# How do I make materials and textures colored at same time when rendering?

Tags: texturing, materials

So I am trying to make a model in Blender. I imported from Roblox and am trying to make GFX for my war group, but for some reason when in material view it shows the helmet and stuff but not the clothes colors. When I go to texture, it swaps, but it always renders in material. I loaded the MTL and the OBJ, but all is shows in render is this. [image: My problem]

That's what shows when I render, it's really weird. Is it a problem with the file I'm uploading, or do I have some settings wrong?? Also, I realize this question has been asked before, but I've tried a lot of fixes and nothing works for me, it's really weird. I've seen blender animations and know that this should be possible, but can't figure out how to do it.
[EDIT] So it shows the textures, but not the colors is what I mean. This post has been up for a while with no answers.
[image: Another Example]

That is what the pieces in the workspace look like.

Comment: Hi are you using cycle ? blender internal ?
Are your models made of multiple objects that are parented or is it one single mesh ?

Comment: Well, I just use render, not cycle. My model is multiple objects that are NOT parented, like all the pieces are sitting in the workspace. I just added another picture in the question, that's how all the pieces are except some are named SmoothBlockModel. When I used cycle, even more color changed to gray. It's really weird. The thing is, the textures show up on their bodies, but not the color. When I change to texture view, colors show.

Comment: Just to be clear, the texture is a color. If you want color from a texture you link the texture to a slot and enable "diffuse color". If you just want a plain color, remove the texture from the material... I'm not too sure what is happening with your blend but it feels like you need to get a few lessons about CG.
The way it works is that any program that lets you do 3d is build with opengl, that is a language. And this language is the KEY to mastering higher lever programs like blender, read a book or some articles about OpenGL.

Comment: Hey @ARobloxPlayer25, could you attach a .blend by uploading it to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? Make sure to use File>External Data>Pack all into .blend

Comment: @WhatAMesh Here is the blend you asked for, [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5262" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5262/)   It turned pink btw, the characters, and that's because I need to load the MTL I know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

THIS PROBLEM IS FIXED! For some reason it randomly didn't work for awhile, but now it does. I just left the thing alone for awhile. Oh well.